# float a(float); meaning?

Tags: c, floating-point

Here is my code snippet:

```
float ab(float);
```

and later

```
if(ab(temp)<ab(a[r][c]))
{ do something; }
```

where

```
float temp;a[6][6];
```

Now what really is this declaration `float ab(float)` and how it is used later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a function prototype. The function is called `ab`; it takes a `float` and returns a `float`. In the `if` statement, `ab(...)` is simply a call to that function.

To figure out what the function does, you'll have to find its definition.

Comment: why do i need if(ab(temp)<ab(a[][]))  and why cant i just do if(temp<a[][]) ??
Also , does it has to be ab only?

Comment: @Karan It is reasonable to believe that the function `ab` does some calucations, which means that `ad(a[r][c])` is not the value value as `a[r][c]`. You can print out the values to check yourself, if you don't have access to the source for the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ohh sorry, i just misunderstood the whole thing.. the function was defined at some other page, and i did not see that.I thought it to be some inbuilt function. 
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The first one,`float ab(float);` is a `Function prototype`

• describes how the function is called

```
float       ab          (float);

return   |  function  | parameter 
type     |  name      | type
```

Now the second case,

```
if(ab(temp)<ab(a[r][c]))
{ do something; }
```

This is nothing but a simple `if`where the condition implies,

> **if (** *the value returned by the function `ab` is less than the value of `a[r][c]`* **)**
>
> {
>
> do something;
>
> }